# Rvest, looping through elements on a page in order to follow a link at each element?

Tags: r, database, web-scraping, data-science, rvest

So I'm trying to scrape data from a site that contains club data from clubs at my school. I've got a good script going that scrapes the surface level data from the site, however I can get more data by clicking the "more information" link at each club which leads to the club's profile page. I would like to scrape the data from that page (specifically the facebook link).

Below you'll see my current attempt at this.

```
url <- 'https://uws-community.symplicity.com/index.php?s=student_group'
page <- html_session(url)

get_table <- function(page, count) {
  #find group names
  name_text <- html_nodes(page,".grpl-name a") %>% html_text()
  df <- data.frame(name_text, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  #find text description
  desc_text <- html_nodes(page, ".grpl-purpose") %>% html_text()
  df$desc_text <- trimws(desc_text)

  #find emails
  #  find the parent nodes with html_nodes
  #  then find the contact information from each parent using html_node
  email_nodes<-html_nodes(page, "div.grpl-grp") %>% html_node( ".grpl-contact a") %>% html_text()
  df$emails<-email_nodes

  category_nodes <- html_nodes(page, "div.grpl-grp") %>% html_node(".grpl-type") %>% html_text()
  df$category<-category_nodes

  pic_nodes <-html_nodes(page, "div.grpl-grp") %>% html_node( ".grpl-logo img") %>% html_attr("src")
  df$logo <- paste0("https://uws-community.symplicity.com/", pic_nodes)

  more_info_nodes <- html_nodes(page, ".grpl-moreinfo a") %>% html_attr("href")
  df$more_info <- paste0("https://uws-community.symplicity.com/", more_info_nodes)

  sub_page <- page %>% follow_link(css = ".grpl-moreinfo a")

  df$fb <- html_node(sub_page, xpath = '//*[@id="dnf_class_values_student_group__facebook__widget"]') %>% html_text()

  if(count != 44) {
    return (rbind(df, get_table(page %>% follow_link(css = ".paging_nav a:last-child"), count + 1)))
  } else{
    return (df)
  }
}


RSO_data <- get_table(page, 0)
```

The current error I'm getting is:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "logo", value = "https://uws-community.symplicity.com/") : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

I know I need to make a function that will go through each element and follow the link, then mapply that function to the dataframe df. However I don't know how I'd go about making that function so that it would work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

your error says that you are trying to combine two different dimensions... your page variable already has one dimension and second is 0. `page <- html_session(url)` add this inside you function.

Comment: doing this creates an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is a reproducable example of your error message.

```
x = data.frame()
x[1] <- c(1)
```

I haven't checked your code, but the error is in there, you have to go step by step through your code. You will find the error, where you've created an empty data.frame and then tried to assign a value to it. 
good luck